# In JavaScript, how can I add animation effect on every image in a modal gallery?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, image-gallery

I have a gallery of images, every one of which gets opened in a modal mode on click. I want to add an animation effect to each one of them to be shown when we next and previous buttons are clicked. I added the animation style to my JS code, however it doesn't work as expected. It only works on the first click, not the rest.

Here is my code:

```js
    var prev = document.querySelector("#prev");
    var next = document.querySelector("#next");
    next.addEventListener("click", nextImage);
    modalImg.addEventListener("click", nextImage);
    prev.addEventListener("click", previousImage);

    function nextImage() {
      if (currentIndex < imgArr.length - 1) {
        currentIndex++;
        modalImg.src = imgArr[currentIndex].style.backgroundImage
          .slice(4, -1)
          .replace(/"/g, "");
      }
      modalImg.style.animation = "fadeInLeft .4s both";
    }

    function previousImage() {
      if (currentIndex > 0) {
        currentIndex--;
        modalImg.src = imgArr[currentIndex].style.backgroundImage
          .slice(4, -1)
          .replace(/"/g, "");
      }
      modalImg.style.animation = "fadeInLeft .4s both";
    }
```

```css
    @keyframes fadeInLeft {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-20px);
        transform: translateX(-20px);
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
        -ms-transform: translateX(0);
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you add a working snippet, that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: Sure. I didn't do it because of its length. But I'll make a snippet now for you to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achive it via manipulate animation via property `animationName` or via manipulate via class name, that have defined animation.

See [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Kyrylo/28wzas4q/)

In any case you should remove animation when it complete

```
function onAnimationEnd(){
/*
  // Options 1: Manipulate class name
  this.classList.remove('fade')
*/
  imgContainer.style.animationName = 'none';
}
imgContainer.addEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEnd);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify to avoid repetition:

```
const prev = document.querySelector("#prev");
const next = document.querySelector("#next")
prev.addEventListener("click", prevImage);
next.addEventListener("click", nextImage);
modalImg.addEventListener("click", nextImage);

function animate(i) {
  modalImg.src = imgArr[i].style.backgroundImage
    .slice(4, -1)
    .replace(/"/g, "");
  modalImg.style.animationName = "fadeInLeft";
}

function nextImage() {
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % imgArr.length;
  animate(currentIndex)
}

function prevImage() {
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + imgArr.length - 1) % imgArr.length;
  animate(currentIndex)
}
```

Or use only one event listener (no need for `prev` and `next` variables):

```
function animate(i) {
  modalImg.src = imgArr[i].style.backgroundImage
    .slice(4, -1)
    .replace(/"/g, "");
  modalImg.style.animationName = "fadeInLeft";
}

function showImage(elem) {
    if (elem.id === "next" || elem.id === "modalImg") {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % imgArr.length;
    } else if (elem.id === "prev") {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + imgArr.length - 1) % imgArr.length;
    } else {
        return currentIndex
    }
    animate(currentIndex)
}

window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    showImage(e.target)
});
```

Comment: That's a great suggestion. However, I changed my code for previous and next buttons using % so that I would be able to loop through the gallery. Is there a way to make it DRY as well? Here is the code: https://codepen.io/leila-ai/pen/mdJxYbj

Comment: I've changed my answer after looking at your code ; )

Comment: This is very nice. Thank you :)